# Objective C: Class architecture for unit conversion

Tags: objective-c, class, architecture, hierarchy

I am a novice objective c programmer with a good amount of experience with other OO languages.

Currently I am working on a calculator that involves some unit conversion.  My initial thought was to have a two abstract classes: *Measurement* and *Unit*.  Subclasses of Unit would be things like *Meter*, *Kilogram*, *Second*, etc.  These classes would contain information about the multiplier to some base unit (probably the SI units) as well as some information useful to the UI like label and description.  Subclasses of Measurement would be things like *Length*, *Mass*, *Time*, etc.  These classes would contain the value and unit of the measurement as well as the methods necessary to determine allowed conversions and conduct the conversions.

I am starting to have questions like "How do I have only one Meter class shared by any Length class that needs it?" and "How do I store a list of allowed units per measurement that is common to any measurement of that type?" This is leading me to believe that I may be over-engineering my class hierarchy.  I was wondering if anyone had suggestions on different architectures to accomplish this task or perhaps language features that a novice may be unaware of that may help with my implementation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Subclassing `Unit` and `Measurement` sounds like overarchitecting, just have instances that represent the various supported measurement+system+magnitude combos, with the magnitude expressed in some reference unit. So you'd have a `Unit(Length, Metric, 'm', 1)` and `Unit(Length, Metric, 'km', 1000)`. A `Measurement` instance would then have a list of `Unit` instances (in various systems) associated with it.

Answer (score 1):

So, I wrote [a unit conversion library in Objective-C](https://github.com/davedelong/DDUnitConverter) and I just used enums.  There's a lookup method in each converter class (a different class for Area, Length, etc), which has a `if()` statement that returns the multiplier for the specified unit into the base unit.  The conversion method then either divides or multiplies by that number, depending on whether you're converting from or to that unit.

Comment: Hollllyyy shit, this is great. Can I use this in an app I'm making for chemistry that I'd like to distribute on the app store?

Comment: Thanks, man. I'm trying to build it on the iPhone, so is there an iOS version of your library? I ask because I don't want to edit your code if I don't have to.

Comment: @doctordoder the same code compiles for iOS and Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Quantity pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/quantity.html).

The important thing is for these classes to act like immutable value objects.

Also, the book *Analysis Patterns* goes into greater detail about *Measurements* and *Observations*. Might be worth a look.

Comment: Thanks for the link, Jordao.  I read the material, and it seems that I have come up with a very similar pattern.  However, I couldn't find much about the implementation of the different units or converting from one to another.  I do think I will implement these "quantity" objects as immutable value classes, as you and the material suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a units of measure library called [UnitsKit](https://github.com/stevemoser/UnitsKit) that does more than your basic conversion. For example, you can multiply m/s by seconds and get meters or feet or any other unit of length.

The basic overview of the class structure starts with SMQuantity that contains a value and a derived unit. A derived unit consists of one or more base units each with their own dimensional exponent. Each base unit is composed of a name, symbol, fundamental unit (m is the fundamental unit of km), scale, static rational and dimension. Take a look.